# How to show changes since last commit in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In order to show local changes since the last commit in TortoiseSVN, I right-click a folder, create a patch and look at the patch. This requires me to create a new file. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy: [**TortoiseSVN | Check for modifications**](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html#tsvn-cli-checkmods). The command's purpose is similar to `svn status --verbose`.

Comment: I didn't realise I could double-click the fils in that window. Thanks!